# Ac unit will not come on

Tags: electrical, air-conditioning

Someone instaled a 240v window ac unit line. They connected the white wire to the ground bar in the panel. The ac unit worked for a little while and turned off. Now the ac unit will not come back on. The breaker has been checked and is good.what could have happened

Comment: Please say what country you are in. This Stack gets questions from around the world, and wiring differs.

Comment: How many wires in the cable without ground?  240 volts need two hots and maybe neutral.  The second hot can be a marked white wire if neutral is not needed.  From what you say you should have two blacks or black and red and a white.

Comment: Does this AC unit plug into an outlet or is it hardwired?  Window units are usually plugged in but there may be exceptions.  If it plugs in then how many prongs on the plug?  Should be three or four prongs, but again if this is a special kind of unit or a "special" kind of electrician that installed it then it can be most anything.  What does the outlet look like?  Does it look like any in this Wiki, and if so then which one? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NEMA_connector#Nomenclature

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.